# Problema con los Fragments y las vistas

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-sqlite

Tengo un lio con las vistas y con los nulos que no me aclaro, me gustaría saber porque me da el siguiente error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.myapplication.ui.listacomida.listacomidaFragment.onCreateView(listacomidaFragment.java:75)

El lo que quiero que haga es que cuando se le pulse al imageButton que haga una función, la función que va a realizar es enviar un layout para que el usuario lo complete, una vez completado se ira a la base de datos de firebase.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        sendViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(listacomidaViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_comida, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, root);
        initViews();
        ImageButton update_button = (ImageButton)root.findViewById(R.id.update_button);
        update_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos=0;
                showUpdateDialog(pos);
            }
        });
        sendViewModel.getMutableLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<FoodModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<FoodModel> foodModels) {
                adapter = new listacomidaAdapter(getContext(), foodModels);
                recycler_lista_comida.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
```

Primero que no entiendo el error, creo que las vistas están bien definidas que es root por eso la utilizo para poder recuperar el id del boton;

Answer (score 0):

Para un fragment Override el método OnCreatedView

```
@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    ImageButton update_button = (ImageButton)root.findViewById(R.id.update_button);
    update_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos=0;
            showUpdateDialog(pos);
        }
    });
    sendViewModel.getMutableLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<FoodModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<FoodModel> foodModels) {
            adapter = new listacomidaAdapter(getContext(), foodModels);
            recycler_lista_comida.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
}
```

Al ser un fragment aun no tienes acceso en el método onCreateView por eso ocurre la  excepción

Comment: A ver, acabo de ver que es que la ImageButton se encuentra en otro layout no en el fragment_lista_comida.

Comment: Adiciona el códigos de los layouts a la pregunta